# Refresh ListView custom simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, listview, refresh, adapter

I wanna delete items in my listview by clicking a button in my list view item. This works but i dont know how to refresh the listview after i clicked the button. can anyone help me?

here is some of my code

```
public class ActionsListView extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button deleteBtn, editBtn, addBtn;
private ListView listView;
DBAdapter myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actions_list_view);

    deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    editBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
    addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alv_AddBtn);

    openDB();
    populateListView();



}
private void openDB(){
    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb.open();
}

private void populateListView(){

    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
    String [] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_ACTION_NAME, DBAdapter.KEY_ACTION_DURATION};
    int [] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.itemActionDisplay, R.id.itemDurationDisplay};
    MySimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_action, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);



}
```

My custom simplecursoradapter

```
public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_action, parent, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    String actionName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ACTION_NAME));
    String actionDuration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ACTION_DURATION));

    TextView actionNameTxtField = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemActionDisplay);
    TextView actionDurationTxtField = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemDurationDisplay);

    actionNameTxtField.setText(actionName);
    actionDurationTxtField.setText(actionDuration);

    Button yourButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view != null) {

                DBAdapter myDb = new DBAdapter(context);
                myDb.open();
                myDb.deleteAll();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `Cursor#requery()`? (i know it is deprecated)

Comment: @pskink thank you for your commen.t Im using swapcursor now, is that better then requery? Im new to programming so i dont no much about efficient programming yet.

Comment: yes, swapcursor is better, BTW you dont need `MySimpleCursorAdapter`, just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: @pskink I have buttons on my ListView items for editing en deleting, i couldnt find how to make these work without a custom SimpleCursorAdapter. I tried the delete all items to see if everything was working correctly. Im struggling to get the item position and row id to delete items separately.